# Two auto-width divs side by side

Tags: css

How can I position two divs with auto width side by side? The left div should take priority. Below is my attempt:

```
<div id='div_1'></div>
<div id='div_2'></div>

#div_1
{
    display:inline-block;    
    float:left;    
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
}

#div_2
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
}
```

EDIT: Adding the goal for clarity -
'The goal is to make the first div be able to autosize itself. The second div should occupy the rest of the space.'

Comment: Well if you change `#div_2` to float left instead, they'll technically be side by side.

Comment: I believe you're looking for something like [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), which is not supported real well yet, I don't think. The alternative is to configure the two as `display: table-cell` with a wrapping element with `display: table` and a `width: 100%`.

Comment: @Jarred Farrish The table-cell method does put both divs side by side, but it malforms (contracts) the first div.

Comment: Here is a demo of the `table` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12650502/451969 (Note, I don't understand your last comment; please make a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate.)

Comment: Note that `float` creates an implicit `display: block`, so even though you set it above each `float`, those `float`s then essentially turn it back to `display: block`. For `table-cell`, you would remove the `float`s (and probably the `position`, unless you need it for something else.). Post a http://jsfiddle.net and it will be easier to make these corrections.

Comment: @Jarred Farrish Here is a very bad JSFiddle which hopefully shows the trouble I am having: http://jsfiddle.net/AdXq5/1/ As you may see, the left column is contracting because of the size of the right column.

Comment: If you don't want the `white-space` to wrap, use [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://jsfiddle.net/AdXq5/2/).

Comment: @Jarred Farrish I was playing with the css and it turns out some paddings and margins were messing up the layout. The table method is working perfectly. Thank you very much. If you post is as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), which is not supported real well yet, I don't think.

An alternative is to configure the two as `display: table-cell` with a wrapping element using `display: table` and a `width: 100%`. See this question for a similar case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650502/451969

What it would give you is something along the lines of:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='div_1'></div>
  <div id='div_2'></div>
</div>

#wrapper
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#div_1
{
    display: table-cell;
}

#div_2
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mDyjE/

Answer (score 0):

Fluid layouts rely on % width value. This is what you should use. For exemple: 50% for both of them.

Moreover, `position: relative` seems to be unnecessary here.

Comment: The goal is to make the first div be able to autosize itself. The second div should occupy the rest of the space.

Comment: On what this auto-width would be based on? You need to indicate it what width you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the goal is to get them to be the same size, side by side. To do this, set width to be about 45% rather than auto. You use 45% because if you use 50% IE will drop the right div below the left.

```
#div_1
{
    display:inline-block;    
    float:left;    
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
}

#div_2
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
}
```

Comment: The goal is to make the first div be able to autosize itself. The second div should occupy the rest of the space.

Comment: By "auto-width", I think the OP wants two divs that "flexes" not represent a fixed but percent width.

Comment: By using % it is not a fixed with.

Comment: It's a fixed percent of the same space; it's relative to it's parent width, not it's sibling width. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes for an alternative.

Comment: If you want the left to auto size, I assume that is based on content? This is a bit more difficult than I thought... I will have to put some more thought into it.

Comment: Yes the size of the first div should be based on content. To be exact, it is based on the length of text inside the div. The other div should occupy the rest of the page then.

Comment: What is to stop the left div from taking 100% of the screen if the content is too long, or the browser width isn't wide enough on a particular resolution? You could always use minimum width on the right div, but that would just cause overlapping under certain situations. Maybe I am not understanding, but this sounds like a resolution and browser type/version nightmare.